# How to model time in matlab?

Tags: matlab, networking

I am implementing a scheme in Matlab in which a particular node A waits for time period t(defined by the distance between the farthest node within A's range and the propagation speed of the signal) for acknowledgements from a set of nodes after sending a message. If it does not receive any acknowledgement with in time period t, it takes some action. 
I have no idea how to implement time in Matlab. Is it possible or I'll have to find some way around?

Comment: You want to wait for a specific amount of time? If yes you should try `pause` command: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html
Otherwise you can create an array or matrix to store the data for each off your timestep.

Comment: @RCaetano: Thank you Sir for your response...wait time is not fixed...it depends on the distance between the sender and the receiver.                   I couldn't understand the second part of your comment. Can you please explain it?  Thanks

Comment: Situations where you have a point moving on a 3D world (location of your signal). You can have a matrix of size [3xT] where the columns are X, Y and Z position and each line indicates the position of the signal at the nth timestep. Example: `[0 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 2 0; 0 3 0]` If a timestep whas defined as 0.5 seconds it would mean that at time 0 the signal was in (0,0,0), time 0.5 at (0,1,0) and so on. So, you could make a `for` to loop the matrix and for each line you could add a `pause(0.5)` or perform another action. The matrix can be created if you have a formula with position dependent on time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MATLAB's powerful [datetime](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html):

For example: you want to check if the signal is received within the acceptable delay (in this example, 40 milliseconds):

```
% t = datetime(Y,M,D,H,MI,S,MS);
send = datetime(2016,08,31,06,01,00,00);
receive=datetime(2016,08,31,06,01,00,100);
acceptableDelay=datenum(40/(24*60*60*1000));

   if ((receive-send)<acceptableDelay)
       disp('Well received!')
   else
       disp('Late!')
   end
```

Comment: One more question. For x=(receive-send) i get x=00:00:00 where receive and send contain different values of time. How can I have the exact value of x displayed till milliseconds. Best Regards

Comment: Try [datestr] (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop#bteqx6c) to show even milliseconds.